# Freeing up array of hashmap buckets in C

Tags: c, linked-list, hashmap

I have implemented a hashmap in C and after quite a bit of work I have gotten everything working great... except for my release routine.

My structs are setup like so:

```
struct hashmap_element {
    int value;
    int key;
    int used;
    struct hashmap_element* next;
};
struct hashmap {
    int table_size;
    int current_size;
    struct hashmap_element* table;
};
```

And my current non-working release routine looks like this:

```
void hm_release(struct hashmap* hm) {
    hashmap_element* tmp;
    hashmap_element* curr_itr; 
    for(int x=0; x<hm->table_size; x++) {
        curr_itr = &hm->table[x];
        while (curr_itr) {
            tmp = curr_itr->next;
            free(curr_itr);
            curr_itr = tmp;
        } 
    }
    free(hm->table);
    free(hm);
}
```

Unfortunately this current segvaults after its first run.  I seem to be having trouble getting my 'curr_itr' to lock onto the first chain of each bucket in the array.  I'm fairly new to using dynamic memory like this in C and have been stuck on this for a few days now.

Everything is being initialized properly as far as I can tell.  Here for example is my hashmap init function.

```
hashmap* hm_initialize() {
    hashmap* hm = malloc(sizeof(hashmap));
    hm->table = (hashmap_element*) calloc(INIT_SIZE, sizeof(hashmap_element));
    hm->table_size = INIT_SIZE;
    hm->current_size = 0;

    // init the buckets
    for (int x=0; x < hm->table_size; x++) {
        hm->table[x].used=0;
        hm->table[x].value=0;
        hm->table[x].key=0;
        hm->table[x].next=NULL;
    }
    return hm;
}
```

Any suggestions/comments would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if you need more of my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start freeing too early,

```
for(int x=0; x<hm->table_size; x++) {
    curr_itr = &hm->table[x];
    while (curr_itr) {
        tmp = curr_itr->next;
        free(curr_itr);
        curr_itr = tmp;
    } 
}
```

The `hashmap_element` `hm->table[x]` was not `malloc`ed, so you shouldn't `free` it.

```
for(int x=0; x<hm->table_size; x++) {
    curr_itr = hm->table[x].next;
    while (curr_itr) {
        tmp = curr_itr->next;
        free(curr_itr);
        curr_itr = tmp;
    } 
}
```

frees only the (hopefully) `malloc`ed `hashmap_element`s after the first in the bucket.

Comment: I think it would be better to have the table as an array of pointers so that all of the `hashmap_elements` can be treated the same.  Then the `used` flag can be removed since unused elements are simply removed from the table.

Comment: Thank you that did help, although I had to use curr_itr = hm->table[x].next instead of curr_itr = hm->table[x]->next.

Comment: @insultant Oops, yes, of course, `hm->table[x]` is not a pointer.